# C++: what happens when you delete a pointer to an object of a class without explicit destructor?

Tags: c++

What happens when you delete a pointer to an object of a class that does not have a declared destructor?

Comment: All classes have destructors, explicit or not; it would call the implicit destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every class (or struct) has a destructor (unless it is a [POD](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType). If you do not declare one the compiler will add an implicit destructor. Take the following class as an example:

```
struct A
{
    std::string test;
};
```

No destructor was defined for A. Yet it has one, because the compiler automatically adds it. It isn't even empty. It would call the destructor of test, because std::string has a destructor itself.

Comment: What does the implicit destructor exactly do?

Comment: @user2460978: Exactly what an explicit destructor with an empty definition would do: run the (nonexistent) code in the destructor body, and then call the destructors for all of the subobjects (in reverse order of declaration in the `struct` or `class` definition).

Comment: By subobjects you mean data members, right? In my opinion the comment is the most important part of the answer.

Comment: @user2460978 there are also subobjects of base classes (if this was a derived class)

Comment: Even POD classes have (implicitly declared) destructors.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ Standard (12.4 Destructors)

> 4 If a class has no user-declared destructor, a destructor is
>   implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4). An implicitlydeclared
>   destructor is an inline public member of its class.
>
> 11... A destructor is also invoked implicitly through use of a **delete- expression** (5.3.5) for a constructed object allocated by a new-expression (5.3.4);

And all destructors do the following except that implicitly defined destructor has an empty body and consequently does not have automatic objects allocated within its body.

> 8 After executing the body of the destructor and destroying any
>   automatic objects allocated within the body, a destructor for class X
>   calls the destructors for X’s direct non-variant non-static data
>   members, the destructors for X’s direct base classes and, if X is the
>   type of the most derived class (12.6.2), its destructor calls the
>   destructors for X’s virtual base classes. All destructors are called
>   as if they were referenced with a qualified name, that is, ignoring
>   any possible virtual overriding destructors in more derived classes.
>   Bases and members are destroyed in the reverse order of the completion
>   of their constructor (see 12.6.2). A return statement (6.6.3) in a
>   destructor might not directly return to the caller; before
>   transferring control to the caller, the destructors for the members
>   and bases are called. Destructors for elements of an array are called
>   in reverse order of their construction (see 12.6).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by delete a pointer p to a class C you mean

```
C *p;
<some init and work>
delete p;
```

If class C does not have a destructor explicitly declared the compiler will add a destructor implicitly.

This implicitly destructor gets called upon destruction of an instance of 
the class doing nothing.

n.b. the implicitly added destructor is inline public.

Answer (score 0):

**Implicitly-declared destructor**
If no user-defined destructor is provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare a destructor as an inline public member of its class.

**Deleted implicitly-declared destructor**
The implicitly-declared or defaulted destructor for class T is undefined (until C++11)defined as deleted (since C++11) if any of the following is true:
T has a non-static data member that cannot be destructed (has deleted or inaccessible destructor)
T has direct or virtual base class that cannot be destructed (has deleted or inaccessible destructors)
T is a union and has a variant member with non-trivial destructor.
(since C++11)
The implicitly-declared destructor is virtual (because the base class has a virtual destructor) and the lookup for the deallocation function (operator delete() results in a call to ambiguous, deleted, or inaccessible function.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int i;

    A ( int i ) : i ( i ) {}

    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "~a" << i << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a1(1);
    A* p;

    { // nested scope
        A a2(2);
        p = new A(3);
    } // a2 out of scope

    delete p; // calls the destructor of a3

}

output:
~a2
~a3
~a1
```